# How to Deploye a Custom jar in Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform

Tags: jar, jboss, jboss-eap-6, deployment-descriptor

I have an custom.jar , ineed to deploy in  my JBOSS EAP 6.2 i tried in the classic method by seeding the JBOSS EAP document but i am not getting it ,,

The steps i had done are

I have a custom Data-source jar say sampledatasource.jar i need to integrate with JBOSS EAP for connecting my Database

i created a module folder in modules

JBOSS

```
|

|__modules

    |

    |__com

        |

        |__ssc

            |

            |__fwa

                |

                |__main

                    |

                    |__module.xml customdatasource.jar dependency1.jar dependency2.jar dependency3.jar
```

and in modules.xml

```
<properties>

    <property name="jboss.api" value="unsupported"/>

</properties>

 <resources>

    <resource-root path="dependencyjar1.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="dependencyjar2.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="dependencyjar3.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="customdatasource.jar"/>

    <resource-root path="dependencyjar4.jar"/>

 </resources>

<dependencies>

    <module name="javax.api"/>

    <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>

    <module name="javax.resource.api"/>

    <module name="javax.security.auth.message.api"/>

    <module name="javax.security.jacc.api"/>

    <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>

    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>

    <module name="javax.xml.bind.api"/>

    <module name="javax.xml.stream.api"/>

    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>

    <module name="org.infinispan"/>

</dependencies>
```

and my domain.xml in ha-ful

i added driver

```
                    <driver name="SampleDs" module="com.ssc.fwa">
                        <datasource-class>com.ssc.faw.util.SampleDatasourceDriver</datasource-class>
                    </driver>
```

and in datasource

```
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//******:1521/OOA2</connection-url>

                    <connection-property name="useExtendedJndiPropertyNames">

                        false

                    </connection-property>

                    <connection-property name="abc">

                        ABC-TDE

                    </connection-property>

                    <connection-property name="bcd">

                        BCD

                    </connection-property>

                    <connection-property name="env">

                        DEV

                    </connection-property>

                    <connection-property name="dataSourceImplementationType">

                        POOLED

                    </connection-property>

                    <connection-property name="actionQualifier">

                        MASTER

                    </connection-property>

                    <connection-property name="dataSourceName">

                        esftdedev

                    </connection-property>

                    <connection-property name="resiliencyDataSourcesStr">

                        String

                    </connection-property>

                    <driver>ResDs</driver>

                    <security>

                        <user-name>USERNAME</user-name>

                        <password>PASSWORD</password>

                    </security>

                    <validation>

                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>

                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>

                    </validation>

                    <statement>

                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>

                    </statement>

                </datasource>
```

i need to know whether all these configurations are working fine or not .I need to see the classes in jar to use it ,

I also used verbose:class to to check whether i can see the classes but i am not able to see it.

now i need to use this jar to map the connections

i think u can understand now.

Please tell me how to configure the custom jar

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so please post some kind of stack trace so we can see what the issue might be.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your modules.xml begins with

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.ssc.fwa">
```

The driver definition looks ok.
The datasource has a mistake, driver element must match your driver's name.. In your example, it would be

```
<driver>SampleDs</driver>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i done so but unfortunatly the same error can  u please help me in depolying this jar because its showing unsatisfied dependencies .. error

Comment: Can you post the missing dependencies log?